# Is the \n supposed to indent your text?

Tags: javascript, auto-indent

I'm a python programmer and in Python, the \n renders a new line like so:

```
print("Hello \n World")
Hello
World
```

But I'm trying to do that in Javascript with the following block of code:

```
if (userInput == wrongAnswer){
    let finalScore = initialScore + scoreForA;
    console.log(finalScore);
    if (finalScore == 5){
        console.log(rightScore);
    }
    else{
        console.log("Initial score:", initialScore, "\n", outputA, "\n", "Final score:", finalScore);
    }
}
```

Edit: By the way, I've defined these variables already.

But it gives me:

[image]

And I'm supposed to make it:
[image]

Is the \n supposed to auto-indent Wrong answer and Final score after making a new line in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you're providing multiple arguments to `console.log`, so the python analog would be `print("Hello\n", "World")` which would add a space on the second line as well. Multiple arguments are always separated by a space, if you don't like that, concatenate them or use a template literal:

```
console.log(`Initial score: ${initialScore}\n${outputA}\nFinal score:${finalScore}`)
```

Comment: So deleting the space after the \n should work: `console.log("Initial score:", initialScore, "\n",outputB, "\n","Final score:", finalScore2);`.  Thanks

Comment: Update: The first idea was wrong.  I did your method and it worked. Also concatenation turned out to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because the function console.log() adds a space between each params.

[image]

You can do that :

```
console.log("Initial score" + 5 +"\n" + "WrongAnswer" +" :(" + "\n" + "Final score -1");
```